# What's the name of this logical fallacy/Wie nennt man diesen Fehlschluss?

Tags: single-word-request

How do you call this logical fallacy?

> I've never heard of <bad thing> happening, so it *cannot* happen!

(Side note: I do not know the name of the fallacy, so it cannot have one. ^^)

---

Ich bin auf der Suche nach einer Bezeichnung für den folgenden Fehlschluss:

> Ich hätte noch nie davon gehört, dass <schlimme Sache> schon mal passiert wäre, also *kann* sie überhaupt nicht passieren!

(...und nachdem ich die Bezeichnung nach der ich frage, nicht kenne, kann sie auch nicht existieren! ^^)

Comment: What's that named in English, and what does the dictionary say about the translation?

Comment: I do not know the name in *any* language. Should I ask somewhere else? I am German, so it was naturally to come here.

Comment: The closest I can think of is _Trugschluss_ or _Denkfehler_. You know that you can ask questions in German here, don't you?

Comment: Ich frage meistens lieber auf Englisch, weil ich auch immer zuerst auf Englisch google. Und es hätte mir in diesem Fall auch schon geholfen, diese Frage auf Englisch mit einer englischen Antwort zu finden, denn die hätte ich ja dann im Wörterbuch nachschauen können. Aber nun habe ich die Frage zweisprachig gestaltet! =)

Comment: _"Ich frage meistens lieber auf Englisch ..."_ Das stiftet u.U. halt auch Verwirrung worauf Du hinaus willst.

Comment: Ich glaube übrigens nicht, dass es für genau diesen Fall einen speziellen Ausdruck außer _Trugschluss_, _Denkfehler_ oder _Fehlschluss_ gibt.

Comment: In einem Forum über Logik oder Philosophie wäre die Frage wahrscheinlich besser aufgehoben.

Comment: @RHa Das sehe ich auch so.

Comment: @Bowi Bei Wikipedia sind gleich mehrere Begriffe genannt, die in diese Kategorie fallen könnten: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fehlschluss Der Titel ist aber immer noch _Fehlschluss_.

Comment: @RHa -- To be fair, this fallacy does not seem to be well known in English; there is no version of the page on the English Wikipedia for example. (It does cover the more general "Argumentum ad populum" though.) I agree that it belongs on the Logic forum, but given that the term seems to be better known in German I can see how it might have landed here instead.

Comment: Vielleicht der Schwarze-Schwan-Fehlschluss?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called

### a nescire ad non esse.

Sources: [Herders Conversations-Lexikon](http://www.zeno.org/Herder-1854/A/a+nescire+ad+non+esse) of 1854 and the [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_nescire_ad_non_esse) based thereon.

Obviously, however, it's merely the Latin version of the paraphrase 'vom Nichtwissen auf Nichtsein (schließen)'.

Answer (score 1):

Im Grunde ist das gar kein Fehlschluss, sondern die natürliche Grundlage menschlichen Denkens und Handelns. Von der Erfahrung ausgehende Erwartungen werden bestätigt oder widerlegt. Was wir hier als Fehlschluss ansehen, ist gewissermaßen das Induktionsproblem. Von bekannten Teilen wird auf ein allgemeineres Ganzes geschlossen. Wir machen das alle jeden Tag, wenn wir z.B. von einem hinter der Häuserecke hervorlukenden Vorderrad auf ein Fahrrad schließen, das da gleich um die Ecke kommt. Es könnte sich theoretisch auch um ein einzelnes Rad handeln, das da durch die Gegend rollt. Davon geht aber niemand aus. Aus Erfahrung schließen wir sofort, dass da jemand mit dem Fahrrad um die Ecke kommt. Induktion ist gewissermaßen eine Abkürzung vom Wahrnehmen zum unmittelbaren Handeln, die uns längeres Betrachten und Beobachten erspart und dadurch schnell reagieren lässt. Induktion spart Zeit, ist aber fehleranfällig.

Aus unserer heutigen Denkweise heraus erscheint der Schluss, dass etwas nicht wahr ist, weil ich es noch nie gehört habe, wie (wie @Christian es nennt) Babylogik. Im Grunde ist aber die Aussage, dass etwas, das noch nie beobachtet wurde, trotzdem eintreten könnte, eine Art von Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung, die wir heute ganz selbstverständlich vornehmen. Unser mathematisch wissenschaftlich geprägtes Weltbild mahnt uns sofort zur Vorsicht: nur weil *ich* das noch nie gehört, gesehen, ... habe, ist keinesfalls sicher, dass es *grundsätzlich* nicht möglich ist. Vor der Entdeckung Australiens wäre die Aussage *Alle Schwäne sind weiß.* in Europa niemandem als Fehlschluss angerechnet worden und letztlich muss jede Theorie wenigstens nachträglich der Erfahrung standhalten.

Die Frage, inwieweit Aussagen über einzelne Beobachtungen hinaus zu neuen Erkenntnissen führen können, ist der Dreh- und Angelpunkt der Erkenntnistheorie von Kant. Urteile über die Wahrscheinlichkeit des Eintretens von Ereignissen, die nicht auf empirischen Daten beruhen, sind synthetische Urteile a priori, die bis heute ein erhebliches Problem darstellen.

Nicht zuletzt durch Popper (und die Quantenmechanik) geht man mehr und mehr dazu über, weniger von der Möglichkeit festen Wissens (a priori oder a posteriori) als vielmehr von Wahrscheinlichkeiten auszugehen. Allerdings hat das menschliche Denken mit Wahrscheinlichkeiten ziemliche Probleme, wie man am Lottospiel leicht sieht. Als überspitzte Umkehrung der Ausgangsfrage könnte man vielleicht sagen:

> Nur weil es extrem unwahrscheinlich ist, dass ich im Lotto gewinne, heißt das nicht, dass ich nächsten Samstag nicht spielen sollte. Es könnte ja doch ...

In gewisser Hinsicht macht das weniger Sinn als die Annahme, dass auch am nächsten Samstag meine Zahlen sicher nicht gezogen werden.

Kurzum handelt es sich also weniger um einen Fehlschluss als um das Induktionsproblem: Inwieweit lässt sich der gegenwärtige Erfahrungsstand verallgemeinern, um zu sicheren Erkenntnissen und Prognosen zu gelangen?

Comment: Ich glaube beim Lotto verspielt man auf einen Euro Einsatz statistisch 60 oder 70 Cent. Das heißt für 30, 40 ¢ bekommt man Futter für die Phantasie, Hoffnung, Spannung und die winzige Chance, Millionär zu werden. Getrübt wird das Glück durch Gebühren pro Lottoschein, die die Rechnung zuungunsten des Spielers noch verschieben.

Comment: Sehr interessante Antwort, vielen Dank! :-)

Answer (score -1):

In my world it is called

> Babylogik

or

> Kleinkindlogik

That's because we observe this fallacy (if you want to call it so) most frequently with little children before a certain stage of cognitive development: if you hide an object from them, they are not anymore aware of its existence. Just from a certain stage of cognitive development on they have a concept of "things out of sight still exist".

It is possible that the wider public is not actively aware of the existence of these terms. Still, to claim they therefore do not exist would be a mistake of *Kleinkindlogik*.

Comment: Viele logische Fehlschlüsse passieren Kindern häufiger als Erwachsenen. Diese Bezeichnungen sind zu abstrakt.